# I have a brightness problem on Ubuntu(18.04 LTS)

Tags: brightness

My computer automatically changes the brightness. 
I don't know why because I'm beginner of Linux itself. 
The cycle of change is about one minutes.
The speed of changes are so fast that my eyes hurt.

I want to ask what I should do, and I wonder if others are having same problem.

Note: My computer is msi laptop. [GE62 2QF] is ths label of laptop.

Comment: Does the brightness adjust darker when you're sitting reading only, or does it get darker even when you are typing?

Comment: Indicate your computer brand and graphical card. Many Intel cards have this "dynamic contrast enhancement" which adapts the clarity of the display to clear or dark content.

Comment: It only changes when I typing.